# App not shown in Windows App Certification Kit

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

My app is not shown in the list of candidates for the Windows App Certification Kit.
Why would it not be shown?
What can I do to have it displayed so that I can run the certification process on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are launching the Certification Kit separately, then it might happen your app is not there - it happend to me too few times.
The right thing to do is launch the Certification Kit directly from Visual Studio, just select your project as the startup project and open PROJECT -> Store -> Create app package -> enter you ID, wait for the package creation and then start the Certification Kit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the WACK tool from the command line.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Create the app package (make sure you are in Release mode)
2. Run the app once from Visual Studio (just ctrl+F5 it)
3. Close the app and follow the steps in the article below.

http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2012/05/06/running-windows-app-certification-kit-wack-tool-from-command-prompt.aspx

Thanks,
Arun